# How do I ignore units in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I'm trying to do a simple calculation of 12 $/h multiplied by some other cells which represent days and hours. This is a simple multiplication on Google Spreadsheet, but in Numbers units are automatically added (ie. 252d, 8h) and this somehow resulting in totally wrong calculation results.

How do I force Numbers to not insert this unwanted extra data? Changing the cell formatting from "automatic" to "number" doesn't seem to have an effect. I want it to behave like other spreadsheet programs.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you have to wrap every formula that generates a duration in DUR2DAYS or DUR2HOURS to convert to a number.